# How to get Web Application url in SharePoint 2013 in Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a "beautiful" and the fastest way to get only the web application url (don't want to trim or substring or anything else).

Comment: Try this : window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host

Comment: Unnie, can you make this an answer so you get your due credit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to find WebApp url, this takes care of port number too (if exists)

```
var WebAppUrl="";
if (location.port)
    {
        WebAppUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + ":" + location.port;
    }
    else
    {
        WebAppUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    }
```